# Setting Up ADFS 2.0 in Virtual Machine

Tags: asp.net, virtual-machine, saml-2.0, adfs, federated-identity

I'm trying to setup a test environment on a Windows 7 professional box wherein I can test building a federated ASP.NET application that connects to an ADFS 2.0 issuer.

My plan is to install Windows Server 2012 (or earlier) in a virtual machine on my Win 7 box.

A) Is this feasible?
B) How exactly would I connect to ADFS inside a virtual machine running on the same box as the ASP.NET application?

Comment: Could you elaborate on point B? what do you mean by connecting 'ADFS inside a virtual machine running on the same box as the ASP.NET application'? ASP.NET is also on the VM? Or it's on the Win7 host? Have you got AD set up?

Comment: Right - the ASP.NET app would be on the host Win7 box, and ADFS running in a virtual machine on that same Win7 host.

Comment: Regarding the "`(or earlier)`" part of the question: as someone who has been through this, you _really_ want Server 2012 R2 (or later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A** Server 2012 can run inside of Virtual Box.

**B** When setting up the VM, you will want to choose the `Bridged networking` networking option. This will make your ADFS guest look like any other computer on your local network.

Comment: Perfect. I'll just go ahead and mark this as answered in lieu of getting it all setup - because I doubt I'm going to get any additional feedback regarding this. I may also try setting up a VM in Azure if things don't work out.